# Google Earth imagery not displayed using SAS.Planet:

Tags: google-earth, sas

I have some trouble using SAS.Planet to download some georeferenced Google Earth images. If I try to open (display) "Earth(GeoCacher direct)" (or basically any other Google Earth option) there are no tiles building up. I just get a grey background. Also there is no Errorcode shown. I updated the Mapversions without any changes. SAS.Planet Version: SAS.Planet.Nightly.201020.10106

Is there a way to get the Google Earth Imagery working in SAS.Planet?

Answer (score 1):

Googleearth(geocache)(direct)(via http), only work with Google Earth cache. It is not like the Google Maps item with http link, and to write then, a cache on the disk. In other words, tiles like those of Google Earth, just by the option Google Maps, or else, tell sasplanet (options - cache) where the Google Earth cache folder is located on the disk, and view it only through sasplanet. That's what this option is for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try zooming in to level 24 and pan around the area you want to download.  Then download the images.  This solved my problem.